# How to stay on our original app when user press cancle button on second app which is opened by custom url scheme IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, url-scheme, uiapplication

I am using custom url scheme to open sms,mail and call apps, on call when user press cancel button,caller app dismisses and my app appears on the screen , but in sms and mail app if user press cancel button it is navigating in the same app. it means that in message app if user press cancel it stays on message app, i want user to get back on my app. i know it can be done because i have seen this thing in whatsapp.

Comment: You should use MFMessageComposeViewController and MFMailComposeViewController and stay in your app rather than using SMS and Mail urls.

Comment: Paulw11 is completely right. No need to use URL's here.

Comment: it is working . thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't use url schemes, instead have a look at sample code from apple.

[This could help you](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MessageComposer/Introduction/Intro.html)